# What software can I use to bring a window into focus on mac?

Tags: osx, automation

I'm looking for a Python library that will let me bring a window into focus on Mac.

On windows, this would be win32gui's SetForegroundWindow function. Is there a Mac equivalent? I've found I can list the available windows using Quartz like this:

```
from Quartz import CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo, kCGNullWindowID, kCGWindowListOptionAll
window_info = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionAll, kCGNullWindowID)
```

However, I've been unable to find a way to programmatically switch to a selected window. FWIW I'm running MacOS Mojave 10.14.5.

Some candidates I've looked at are `pyautogui` and `pygetwindow`. The former doesn't offer the desired functionality, and the later is only for windows.